# Invoke from outside of a class .NET

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli, invoke

i am usinng Visual Studio C++ 2010.

I want to make thread-safe change in GUI from other than main thread, from function declared outside of a main Form class. Here is some code i have:

**Outside of a main class:**

```
public delegate void DEBUGDelegate(String^ text);
```

(...)

```
int lua_debug(lua_State *L){
    // boolean debug(message)
    Globals^ Global = gcnew Globals;
    String^ debugMsg = gcnew String(lua_tostring(L, 1));

    DEBUGDelegate^ myDelegate = gcnew DEBUGDelegate(Global->FORM, &Form1::DEBUGDelegateMethod);
    Global->FORM->Invoke(myDelegate, gcnew array<Object^> { "HEYO! \r\n" });

    lua_pushboolean(L, true);
    return 1;
}
```

**Inside of a main class:**

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

(...)

    public: void DEBUGDelegateMethod(String^ text)
    {
            this->DEBUGBOX->Text += text;
    }

(...)

    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        Globals^ Global = gcnew Globals;
        Global->FORM = this;
    }

    private: System::Void button1_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        Globals^ Global = gcnew Globals;
        DEBUGDelegate^ myDelegate = gcnew DEBUGDelegate(this, &Form1::DEBUGDelegateMethod);
        this->Invoke(myDelegate, gcnew array<Object^> { "HEYO! \r\n" });
    }
}
```

**So the problem is that if i comment function "lua_debug" and the rest stays untoutched, it works fine and clicking on button1 makes text appears on debug textbox. When i uncomment the part with lua_debug, there is an error:**

```
d:\prog\c++\x\x\Form1.h(146): error C2653: 'Form1' : is not a class or namespace name
1>d:\prog\c++\x\x\Form1.h(146): error C2065: 'DEBUGDelegateMethod' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\prog\c++\x\x\Form1.h(146): error C3350: 'X::DEBUGDelegate' : a delegate constructor expects 2 argument(s)
```

146 line is:

```
DEBUGDelegate^ myDelegate = gcnew DEBUGDelegate(Global->FORM, &Form1::DEBUGDelegateMethod);
```

**===================================================
@EDIT**

After moving lua_debug after Form1 declaration, i get this error:

```
d:\prog\c++\x\x\Form1.h(1829): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from    'System::Windows::Forms::Form ^' to 'X::Form1 ^'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          Cast from base to derived requires safe_cast or static_cast
1>d:\prog\c++\x\x\Form1.h(1829): error C3754: delegate constructor: member function    'X::Form1::DEBUGDelegateMethod' cannot be called on an instance of type 'System::Windows::Forms::Form ^'
```

in line:

```
DEBUGDelegate^ myDelegate = gcnew DEBUGDelegate(Global->FORM, &Form1::DEBUGDelegateMethod);
```

Global->FORM is declared as:

```
static Form^ FORM;
```

in Globals class.

Comment: Looks like the lua_debug function can't see the Form1 type (the first error indicates this, the other two are consequence of the first one). I think some info is missing. Is Form1 defined inside a namespace? Are lua_debug and Form1 in the same file? Which one goes first? #includes? #pragmas?

Comment: Form1 is defined inside of namespace, lua_debug and Form1 are both in Form1.h file, lua_debug is declared first, then comes Form1 - lua_debug is called in new thread created by buttonclick on Form1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving `lua_debug`'s definition below `Form1`'s, or forward declare `Form1` as you did for `DEBUGDelegateMethod`. I'm assuming they are both inside the same namespace (`lua_debug` and `Form1`). If not, in line 146, you must preprend the namespace, i.e.: `&YourNamespace::Form1::DEBUGDelegateMethod`.

**Edit: (as per OP's edit)**

Just downcast:

```
DEBUGDelegate^ myDelegate = gcnew DEBUGDelegate( dynamic_cast<X::Form1^>(Global->FORM ), &Form1::DEBUGDelegateMethod);
```

Comment: there is new error: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from    'System::Windows::Forms::Form ^' to 'X::Form1 ^'